# warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getresuid’ (and ‘seteuid’)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I would like to get rid of the warnings. When I compile the source code with

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -o test test.c
```

I get back

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getresuid’
test.c:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘seteuid’
```

When I compile it without **-ansi** switch

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

I see on the terminal

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getresuid’
```

I would like to use **-ansi** switch and get rid of warnings. How can I achieve my goal ?

```
/*  this is the test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define __USE_GNU 1
#define __USE_BSD 1

int main()
{
   static uid_t euid, ruid, suid;

   getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);  

   seteuid(getuid()); 

   return 0;
}
```

Environment:

> CentOS 6.3  32-bit
>   gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

Comment: I've added (implemented) the solution proposed by Yu Hao. The original post reflects the change

Comment: I've removed the solution part you added, because that's not how SO works, you should leave the question as it was.

Comment: @Yu Hao Well,  I'd noticed that you've removed detailed solution from my posting. Honestly, I do not understand __why__.  I haven't modified the initial post, I just ADD-ed the solution. Since, I've newbie in C, I thought that a detailed solution could help other newbies. People like to learn by example, for example,  seeing 'wrong' approach and then the 'right' version. It shortens the learning.   But, as I see it now, this is not recommended. I can live with that.

Comment: You can add your solution. But don't put it in your question, add it as an answer. Yes, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`getresuid()` and `seteuid()` are GNU extension function, add

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

**before** including all the headers, or add `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in GCC options.

You shouldn't define `__USE_GNU` macro directly, it's supposed to be used only internally in glibc.

Comment: It outputs the same warning, at least for me. What I did is `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: This header file is also the solution when doing `cmake`, `make`, on macOS Monterey, when building https://github.com/frida/xz.git