# Is getresuid deprecated in c99?

Tags: c, linux, macos, c99, setuid

I'm trying to compile a function containing a call to `getresuid`. However it generates the following warning:

```
setuid.c:8:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getresuid' is invalid
in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
^

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_getresuid", referenced from:
_main in setuid-ba46f8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Why is there a linker error saying symbol not found for architecture x86_64? How do you get it to successfully link?

If it helps, my original code was:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    uid_t euid, ruid, suid;
    getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
    printf("EUID: %d, RUID: %d, SUID: %d\n", euid, ruid, suid);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to compile on Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite).

Comment: The direct answer is "No; `getresuid()` is simply not part of C99 — nor of POSIX 2008 (2013)".  So to use it, you have to use a platform-specific extension.  You don't need `#include <sys/types.h>` in your code.  Your code compiles OK for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  Which version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I think that C99 forbids implicit declarations, not `getresuid()`, that what causes confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Mac OS 10.10.2? Sorry this might be a stupid question, but what extension would you need (and where can you find references)?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.10.2 is not a variant of Linux; it is a variant of BSD.  The `getresuid()` function simply isn't available on Mac — it isn't implemented.  You'll need to use `getuid()` and `geteuid()` for the 'r' and 'e' parts; I'm not sure there's a way to get the 's' part.  Please note that identifying the platform accurately in the question would have helped avoid going down various dead ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define before all the headers

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

as `getresuid` is a GNU extension function.

Comment: I did that in my original code. It still gives the same error.

Comment: @cathy:- Did you try to add `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in GCC options? Also make sure that you added the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before all the headers in your file.

Comment: Yup. I did read through another SO post that suggested all of those things. I believe the main difference in my error above is the linker error. The relevant SO post is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721810/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-getresuid-and-seteuid?rq=1

Comment: @cathy: When you defined `_GNU_SOURCE`, did you get a compilation warning, or just the linker error?

Comment: Both. gcc setuid.c yields the following:

Comment: setuid.c:8:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getresuid' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
  ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_getresuid", referenced from:
      _main in setuid-d2be64.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: @cathy: ideally, you should identify which version of Linux you're using.  What do you get from `grep -l -e getresuid -r /usr/include`?  You should get `/usr/include/unistd.h` and sundry files in sub-directories listed.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is "No; `getresuid()` is simply not part of C99 — nor of POSIX 2008 (2013)". So to use it, you have to use a platform-specific extension, and it is not available on all platforms.

Incidentally, you don't need `#include <sys/types.h>` in your code.

Your code compiles OK for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  However, it fails to compile on Mac OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite), which is derived from BSD rather than Linux.  The `getresuid()` function is simply not available — not implemented — on the platform.

You'll need to use `getuid()` and `geteuid()` for the 'r' (real UID) and 'e' (effective UID) information; I don't think there's a sensible way to get the 's' (saved UID) information.  Most of the time, the three UID values are the same.  Only a program that expects to be run with the 'setuid' bit set needs to worry about these, and such programs might want to worry about the saved UID.  However, you're probably limited to inspecting the effective UID when the program starts; that's the saved UID.